# ID column in Big Query while loading data from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, google-bigquery

I am reading excel data using Python dataframe and want to load into Big Query. I want to have unique id for every row in the table as I have to join that with other tables. What's the best way to have unique id in Big Query? Google doesn't have any auto increment or sequence field like Oracle or MYSQL.

Should I create a uniqueId column in the dataframe while loading the data into table?

Answer (score 0):

You can load in 2 ways, first is to generate values in python through the use of `UUID`.

Through **python**:

```py
import uuid
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4,1), columns=list('a'), index=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four'])


# generate uuid based on the number of rows, I got this from this SO post ---> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48837006/add-uuid-to-a-new-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe#comment85346571_49169227
df['uuid'] = [uuid.uuid4() for x in range(len(df))]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
(venv) a@cloudshell:~/python_cases (a)$ python 20220608.py
              a                                  uuid
one   -0.238813  99c335d2-4c42-4bd2-9f44-493d46184afa
two    1.883587  5dbb57f4-6cab-4640-a360-3e05a55d7d96
three -0.814068  5fdbe914-8116-40f4-b7bd-09a5a2fb3447
four  -0.414967  d2d033c0-8228-42a8-8cf5-8e0277f086eb
```

Second is to load data to **Bigquery** and use [`row_number`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/numbering_functions#row_number) function: `row_number() over (order by field_name) as row_id`, this will yield incremental field results.

Comment: Thank you. In the second step, I will have to alter the table to add the id field after I have inserted the data. So, may be first approach is better but will that ensure the unique id if I have to load the data in multiple batches over time.

Comment: Glad my answer helped you, you can check this SO guidelines, [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=Choose%20one%20answer%20that%20you,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.)